# python- Type Error: '<' between instances of Node and Node

Tags: python

i'm new to python and i'm having this error and i tried several things to solve it but i couldn't find any that's working

```
Type Error: '<' between instances of Node and Node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) for comparison. heapq will internally perform comparisons on elements being added to the heap, your code fails since the element being added is an object and object by default cannot perform comparisons.

We need to define Special methods  __lt__ (<) or __gt__ (>) in order to compare two objects.

For example in your program,, you can add __lt__ method under class Node like below, to compare on freq property of class Node.

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.freq < other.freq
```

Now, you can perform < comparisons on objects, similarly you can write for >, >=, <= or == comparisons as well.